# workbench editor warns of false error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I haven't found an answer to this issue, so I'm posting here.  I'll be the first to admit I may not have conducted the search with the correct terms.

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 Community Edition to connect to the local instance of 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server on my Mac running Yosemite.

My issue is that some commands get underlined in red with an `'x'` on the line indicating an error, but they execute without error.  Here is an example:

> ALTER TABLE products MODIFY created_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

The word `"DEFAULT"` is underlined in red and hovering over it reviews the message `"Syntax error: unexpected 'DEFAULT' (default)"`.  However, the statement executes without error.

Here is the DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  product_id        INT,
  prod_name     VARCHAR(30),
  prod_weight       DECIMAL(6,3),
  created_ts        TIMESTAMP
  );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Workbench showing underlined text indicating error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUZw.png)

Comment: Which MySQL version you use? I tried your code, and workbench dont show me any error. I have Workench 6.3 version too and Mysql version 5.6.1. OS Windows.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 Community Edition to connect to the local instance of 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server on my Mac running Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug fixed in MySQL Workbench 6.3.5: [bug report link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77549)

> Posted by developer:   Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.3.5 release, and here's the changelog entry:
>
> The SQL parser and grammar was updated; some queries would emit bogus
>   errors.
>
> Thank you for the bug report.

Comment: I upgraded to 6.3.6 and the error went away.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be unfixed in Workbench v.6.3.7. I'm seeing tons of false error highlights. (The queries run normally.)

Comment: Same with my Workbench 6.3.7. The bug is reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82741